# Installed custom fontface but some weights are not available in certain applications

Tags: fonts, gimp, inkscape

I've installed an open source typeface, which comes with different weights from *thin* up to *black*. When browsing installed fonts with, say, Fontmatrix, all weights are properly shown. Same is true when I select any of the font weights in a libre office application. However, graphic tools like GIMP and Inkscape lack at least one of the installed typeface weights. It's always the thinnest of the available weights which is called *Thin*. The typeface in question is Roboto.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.10. The truetype files are placed in:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/roboto/
```

I have already copied this truetype directory including all files to:

```
~/.fonts
```

And:

```
~/.gimp-2.8/fonts/
```

I did `sudo fc-cache -fv` as several times as well.

What could GIMP and Inkscape prevent from providing Roboto Thin?

Comment: The only good fix I've found is to rename the weights so Inkscape recognizes them differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download newer version of font https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Roboto